# Oracle 11g: shuffling VARCHAR2 column to get random mapping

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have something like that ([FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eb06/1/0):

```
CREATE TABLE COMPANY(
     id int primary key, 
     name varchar2(20)
)
```

I entered sample data:

```
+------+----------+
|  ID  |   NAME   |
+------+----------+
|  1   |   John   |  
|  4   |  Albert  |
|  6   |   Anna   |
+------+----------+
```

I need to have select that returns all names and new mapped name (randomly).
I have achieved it by writing something like this:

```
with names as (select distinct name from company)
select oldvar, newvar
  from (select rownum as id, name as oldvar from names) o,
       (select rownum as id, 
               name as newvar 
        from (select name from names order by dbms_random.value)) n
where o.id = n.id
```

(Note that: I **DON'T** AND I **CAN'T** use `COMPANY.ID` )

Can anyone optimalize this SQL statement? Maybe it can be done in better, more Oracle specific way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `row_number` to create a random pair:

```
with    names1 as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as rn
        ,       name
        from    Company
        )
,       names2 as
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by dbms_random.value) as rn
        ,       name
        from    Company
        )
select  n1.name as name1
,       n2.name as name2
from    names1 n1
join    names2 n2
on      n1.rn = n2.rn
```